# Error while creating AWS::SNS:Subscription through Cloudformation on LocalStack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns, localstack

#### Current Behavior

An error occurs while using

`awslocal cloudformation deploy --template-file infrastructure.yaml --stack-name teststack`

on this `infrastructure.yaml`

```
Parameters:

  Environment:
    Default: svts
    Description: Deployment environment
    Type: String

  AwsSt:
    Default: test
    Description: Project technical service
    Type: String

  AwsTeam:
    Default: fra
    Description: Team id
    Type: String

  Component:
    Default: relm-adapter
    Description: An identifier for the app
    Type: String

Resources:

  CreateAccountEventQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: !Sub "${AwsTeam}_${AwsSt}_${Environment}_sqs_create_account_event"
      RedrivePolicy:
        deadLetterTargetArn: !GetAtt CreateAccountEventDLQueue.Arn
        maxReceiveCount: 3

  CreateAccountEventDLQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: !Sub "${AwsTeam}_${AwsSt}_${Environment}_sqs_dlq_create_account_event"

  QueuePolicy:
    Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
    Properties:
      Queues:
        - !Ref CreateAccountEventQueue
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: sns.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sqs:SendMessage
            Resource: "*"
            Condition:
              ArnEquals:
                aws:SourceArn:
                  !Sub "${AwsTeam}_${AwsSt}_${Environment}_sns_create_account_event_topic"

  CreateAccountEventSubscription:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    Properties:
      TopicArn: !Sub "${AwsTeam}_${AwsSt}_${Environment}_sns_create_account_event_topic"
      Endpoint: !GetAtt CreateAccountEventQueue.Arn
      Protocol: sqs

  CreateAccountEventTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      DisplayName: !Sub "${AwsTeam}_${AwsSt}_${Environment}_sns_create_account_event_topic"
      TopicName: !Sub "${AwsTeam}_${AwsSt}_${Environment}_sns_create_account_event_topic"
```

The stack creation fails with this error (retrieved from `awslocal describe-stack-events`):

```
{
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:000000000000:stack/teststack/f91977a8",
            "EventId": "36f1855e-d41e-410a-a2cb-2d08b61f8918",
            "StackName": "teststack",
            "LogicalResourceId": "CreateAccountEventSubscription",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:000000000000:stack/teststack/f91977a8",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::SNS::Subscription",
            "Timestamp": "2024-01-30T09:42:19.531000Z",
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_FAILED",
            "ResourceStatusReason": "An error occurred (InternalError) when calling the Subscribe operation (reached max retries: 4): exception while calling sns.Subscribe: not enough values to unpack (expected 6, got 1)"
},
```

This is the error log:

```
2024-01-30 10:47:53 2024-01-30T09:47:53.376 ERROR --- [   asgi_gw_0] l.aws.handlers.logging     : exception during call chain: not enough values to unpack (expected 6, got 1)
2024-01-30 10:47:54 2024-01-30T09:47:54.202 ERROR --- [   asgi_gw_0] l.aws.handlers.logging     : exception during call chain: not enough values to unpack (expected 6, got 1)
2024-01-30 10:47:54 2024-01-30T09:47:54.932 ERROR --- [   asgi_gw_0] l.aws.handlers.logging     : exception during call chain: not enough values to unpack (expected 6, got 1)
2024-01-30 10:47:56 2024-01-30T09:47:56.430 ERROR --- [   asgi_gw_0] l.aws.handlers.logging     : exception during call chain: not enough values to unpack (expected 6, got 1)
2024-01-30 10:47:58 2024-01-30T09:47:58.517 ERROR --- [   asgi_gw_0] l.aws.handlers.logging     : exception during call chain: not enough values to unpack (expected 6, got 1)
2024-01-30 10:47:58 2024-01-30T09:47:58.521  WARN --- [functhread12] l.s.c.resource_provider    : Error calling <bound method ClientCreator._create_api_method.<locals>._api_call of <botocore.client.SNS object at 0xffff4efcfc10>> with params: {'TopicArn': 'test_fra_svts_sns_create_account_event_topic', 'Protocol': 'sqs', 'Endpoint': 'arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:000000000000:test_fra_svts_sqs_create_account_event', 'Attributes': {}} for resource: {'Type': 'AWS::SNS::Subscription', 'LogicalResourceId': 'CreateAccountEventSubscription', 'Properties': {'TopicArn': 'test_fra_svts_sns_create_account_event_topic', 'Endpoint': 'arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:000000000000:prov_fra_svts_sqs_create_account_event', 'Protocol': 'sqs'}, 'SpecifiedProperties': {'TopicArn': 'test_fra_svts_sns_create_account_event_topic', 'Endpoint': 'arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:000000000000:test_fra_svts_sqs_create_account_event', 'Protocol': 'sqs'}}
```

#### Expected Behavior

It should create my stack resources

#### How are you starting LocalStack?

With a `docker run` command

#### Steps To Reproduce

Running localstack from Docker Desktop with port 4566 exposed and /var/run/docker.sock mounted

#### Environment

```markdown
- OS: Ubuntu 23.10 / MacOs Sonoma 14.3
- LocalStack: LocalStack version: 3.1.1.dev
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing it to reference the topic ARN using `!Ref` to ensure the topic is done being created before CloudFormation tries to subscribe to it and to ensure it is getting the ARN and not the name.

The topic ARN in your example does not look like an ARN, so it could be that.  It looks like you have specified the topic name.

```
  CreateAccountEventSubscription:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    Properties:
      TopicArn: !Ref CreateAccountEventTopic
      Endpoint: !GetAtt CreateAccountEventQueue.Arn
      Protocol: sqs
```

The examples on [this documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sns-topic.html#cfn-sns-topic-subscription) show referencing the topic ARN as `TopicArn: !Ref CarSalesTopic` as a reference.